# Why does python get confused by these comparisons?

Tags: python, precision, floating-accuracy

If I run this code in Python 3.8.6 I get the output `False`:

```py
(((3980 - 91 + 1)/(3980)) * ((1 / 3980)**(91 - 1))) > (((3981 - 91 + 1)/(3981)) * ((1 / 3981)**(91 - 1)))
```

However, [if I run this in WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%283980%20-%2091%20%2B%201%29%2F%283980%29%29%20*%20%28%281%20%2F%203980%29**%2891%20-%201%29%29%29%20%3E%20%28%28%283981%20-%2091%20%2B%201%29%2F%283981%29%29%20*%20%28%281%20%2F%203981%29**%2891%20-%201%29%29%29) it returns `True`.

I'm guessing this happens due to float imprecision. But why does it happen exactly here? Out of 12 million combinations of `s` and `z` that I've tested for the following function this only happens twice. `z = 91` with `s = 3980` and `z = 92` with `s = 3457`.

```py
(((s - z + 1)/(s)) * ((1 / s)**(z - 1))) > ((((s+1) - z + 1)/(s+1)) * ((1 / (s+1))**(z - 1)))
```

Also, try these in your interpreter:

1. `(((3458 - 92 + 1)/(3458)) * ((1 / 3458)**(92 - 1))) > (((3459 - 92 + 1)/(3459)) * ((1 / 3459)**(92 - 1)))`
2. `(((3457 - 92 + 1)/(3457)) * ((1 / 3457)**(92 - 1))) > (((3458 - 92 + 1)/(3458)) * ((1 / 3458)**(92 - 1)))`
3. `(((3456 - 92 + 1)/(3456)) * ((1 / 3456)**(92 - 1))) > (((3457 - 92 + 1)/(3457)) * ((1 / 3457)**(92 - 1)))`

They give these results:

1. `True`
2. `False`
3. `True`

Why does the pattern `True False True` happen at only these inputs? Holding `z` constant, no other value of `s` returns `False`.

Comment: It is really not clear what kind of answer you are expecting. "But why does it happen exactly here?" has several answers, from deeply philosophical to floating point math, down to "because you've arbitrarily chosen this unwieldy formula that happens to have these two odd points".

Comment: The raw formula and filled-in formula shown do not seem to match. The trailing term ``((1 / s+1)**(z - 1))`` is equivalent to ``(((1 / s) + 1)**(z - 1))`` not ``((1 / (s+1))**(z - 1))``; for ``s, z = 3980, 91`` that is ``(((1 / 3980) + 1)**(91 - 1)) == 1.0228677735155611`` not ``((1 / 3981)**(91 - 1)) == 0.0``. Which of these formulas as you asking about, and which have you probed?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You're totally correct, thank you for pointing that out. I fixed the formula, it was really just being used in an f-string format, so the order of precedent would be correct there.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I want to know why the `True False True` pattern happens with these inputs. It doesn't happen anywhere else.

Comment: FYI WolframAlpha looks like it uses Fractions and has more precision.  There is an "Exact Form" button that lists the difference as a fraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounding error. If you want to know precisely go read the IEEE 754 specification. Your numbers are so small they are in the subnormal range and have 5-10 bits of precision in your examples.  Floats in the normal range have 53 bits of precision.

---

If you look at the two values using `float.hex()` it shows their exact binary representation:

```
>>> (((3980 - 91 + 1)/(3980)) * ((1 / 3980)**(91 - 1))).hex()
'0x0.0p+0'
>>> (((3981 - 91 + 1)/(3981)) * ((1 / 3981)**(91 - 1))).hex()
'0x0.0p+0'
```

They are both so small at IEEE 754 `float64` precision they are both rounded to zero.  If fact the last term is *really* small:

```
>>> ((1/3981)**89).hex()
'0x0.0000000000327p-1022'
```

Comment: That can’t be the reason, try with 3982 and you’ll see it returns the correct result (`True`).

Comment: @Conner That is the hexadecimal representation of the *exact* value stored in memory.   Both calculate to zero.

Comment: but then why would it return True at all larger values of `s`?

Comment: @Conner print the hex() values and see if they have a difference.  I get the same zero answer for 3982.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is, as you guessed, `float imprecision`.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I guessed it was float imprecision. I want to know *why* the `True` `False` `True` pattern happens in the above examples.

Comment: @Conner Rounding error due to numbers at the very edge of floating point representation.

Answer (score 1):

`Mark Tolonen` answered your question and if you need more precision, use [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> (Fraction(3980 - 91 + 1, 3980) * Fraction(1, 3980) ** (91 - 1)) > (Fraction(3981 - 91 + 1, 3981) * Fraction(1, 3981) ** (91 - 1))
True
```